# Make file for multiple programs

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have `p1.c` `p2.c` ... `pn.c`, a `sharedprg.c` and a `sharedprg.h` files in a directory, I want to create a make file to compile all these programs, for example something like this

```
for i in {1..n}    // just a pseudo code to tell what's in my mind
   gcc -o p$i p$i.c sharedprg.c
```

And every time I invoke `make` it should just re compile `pi` if `pi.c` changed or-else compile all the programs if either `sharedprg.c` or `shareprg.h` changed. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Edit: I would get the result which I wanted using this code

```
shared = sharedMem.c sharedMem.h
all: p1 p2 p3 

%.o: %.c 
    gcc -c $^

p1: p1.o $(shared) 
    gcc -o p1 p1.o sharedMem.c

p2: p2.o $(shared) 
    gcc -o p2 p2.o sharedMem.c

p3: p3.o $(shared) 
    gcc -o p3 p3.o sharedMem.c

clean:
    rm -f *.o p1 p2 p3
```

But please suggest if there is a better or easier way (with out adding `$(shared)` everywhere)

Comment: Maybe, collect a variable with all targets (executables you want to build) first.
Then write rules with wild cards to describe the dependencies between the target to the resp. source files. ([Learn Makefiles](https://makefiletutorial.com/))

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `$^` to `$<` in the compile rule, you can add the extra header prerequisites separately. You can also add prerequisites to multiple targets at once. Some inspiration:

```
# default target; build all
all: p1 p2 p3

# Fix compile rule to only compile the source (excluding any header prerequisites)
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<

# programs depend on their respective .o (Static Pattern Rule)
# https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html
p1 p2 p3: %: %.o

# all objects depend on sharedMem.h
p1.o p2.o p3.o: sharedMem.h

# all programs depend on sharedMem.o (which is made from sharedMem.c)
p1 p2 p3: sharedMem.o
```

The built-in rules do this for you, so you can remove the `gcc ...` recipe line. If you're a beginner, easiest stick to them. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Comment: Just to note, your `p1 p2 p3: %: %.o` isn't needed: there is a built-in rule for building a program from its `.o` file.  You do want to add an initial `all` target, like `all: p1 p2 p3` so that running `make` by itself builds all the programs.

Comment: @MadScientist I thought the built-in only applied if there weren't any other object file prerequisites, which is not the case as sharedMem.o is also a prerequisite.

Comment: Built-in rules will be searched if there are no user-defined implicit or explicit rules that could build the target in question.